# Nestjs: Accessing global Response object in controllers?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I wonder if it is possible to access/assign global Response object in a controller.

I can do it like this;

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  private readonly request: Request;
  private readonly response: Response;
  private readonly service: AppService;

  constructor(
    @Inject('REQUEST') request: Request,
    @Inject(AppService) service: AppService,
  ) {
    this.request = request;
    this.response = request.res; // Yes, it is there where I only could find it.
    this.service = service;
  }

  // ...
```

I get no error if I use `@Res()` stuff;

```js
  @Get('/xml')
  getXml(@Res() response: Response): void {
    // Still using "this.response, .." here, also only "response, .." OK.
    sendXml(this.response, this.service.getXml());
  }
```

I get error if I drop `@Res()` stuff;

```js
  @Get('/xml')
  getXml(): void {
    sendXml(this.response, this.service.getXml());
  }
```

Send XML util;

```js
export function sendXml(response: Response, promise: Promise<any>): void {
  promise = Promise.resolve(promise).then(res => res.text());
  promise.then(data => {
    response.status(200).send(data);
  }).catch(error => {
    // Logged error is caught here, but no 500 code was sent.
    response.status(500).send(error);
  });
}
```

Error;

```
Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/kerem/dev/nestjs/foo/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/kerem/dev/nestjs/foo/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:264:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/kerem/dev/nestjs/foo/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at /home/kerem/dev/nestjs/foo/src/util/index.ts:51:26
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

*I would like to get rid off `@Res()` stuff for each method assigning `response` property once, actually.*

Comment: looks like a bug. I don't believe that just calling `@Res()` or not should change anything. Write a minimum repo and report it on their repo: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues

Comment: Why do you want to call `res.send` inside the service? Why not just return the xml to the controller and let it return? Without the `@Res()`, Nest will try to `res.send()` as well, so you get the error of trying to double send like you see above

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Because it differs what controller methods return, and also I would like to simplify "send response" process as much as possible, say one-line-simple. Otherwise, I always need to do same things, say `this.service.getXml().then(..).then(..).catch(..)` etc (it comes after using `fetch()`), both defining controller methods `async` and using `await` stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you'd need to add the response object though, Why not have this `getXml()` method do the processing necessary and let the controllers stay logicless and just return the service method's return

Comment: @JayMcDoniel 
I did not understand what is logic-less. I just want to see clear/concise controller methods. So this is clearer `getXml() { sendXml(this.response, this.service.getXml()); }` than `getXml(): Promise<any> { this.service.getXml().then(res => res.text()).then(...); }`. I would be glad to that if any suggestion you provide.

Comment: Why not make the service method somethjing like `const res = await fetch(url); return res.text()` and then have the controller do `return this.service.getXml()` so that the controller has absolutely no logic, just calling the service and returning it's response

Comment: Yes I can, but the only problem is not that. 
This is another method: `@Get('/bug/:id')
  getBug(@Res() response: Response, @Param('id') id: string): void {
    send(this.response, this.service.findBug(int(id)));
  }`
And this is service method: `async findBug(id: number): Promise<Bug> {
    return await this.bugRepository.findOne(id);
  }`

So `getXml()` should return text but `getBug()` should return JSON. Thus I tried to create util functions and to put all in it in a proper order.

Comment: I still don't understand why you're letting the service handle sending the response instead of letting the controller do it. It doesn't make sense and is an anti-pattern of the framework